# Tweets Streaming Service unable to write to HBase table on Azure HDInsight HBase cluster

Tags: c#, azure, hbase, azure-hdinsight, tweetinvi

I am following Microsoft's official Azure documentation: [**Analyze real-time Twitter sentiment with HBase in HDInsight**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hbase-analyze-twitter-sentiment/) tutorial to create a simple real-time tweets streaming service which will write tweets into a **HBase table** hosted on Azure HDInsight HBase cluster.

I have set my Twitter app credentials correctly.
I am using the latest **Microsoft HBase .NET Library** and the latest **[TweetinviAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI/)** .NET C# library (0.9.10.1).

```
var credential = Auth.SetUserCredentials(TWITTERAPPAPIKEY, TWITTERAPPAPISECRET, TWITTERAPPACCESSTOKEN, TWITTERAPPACCESSTOKENSECRET);
var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream(credential);
```

I couldn't understand the reason behind why there is no real-time tweets write into my HBase table from my streaming service program.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please update to version 0.9.10.2 that has been released today.
There was a bug affecting the Streams.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I try with the latest nuget version as mentioned above but it's still not working

Comment: Hi, could you let me know if the stream is running or not. You can check when a stream start and when it stop with the following events ([stream error handling](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Streams#stop-and-error-handling) : 

    stream.StreamStopped += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var exceptionThatCausedTheStreamToStop = args.Exception;
        var twitterDisconnectMessage = args.DisconnectMessage;
    };

Answer (score 0):

Met the same issue with the latest Tweetinvi.

The old version (0.9.3.3) works for me.

Comment: When you say latest you do mean 1.0?
Could you let me know how you set your credentials?

Comment: I actually tried the "latest" several weeks ago, where I installed from nuget. I noticed the way to set credential was different. Currently I am using the old one, which is TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials(a,b,c,d);. I will try the 1.0 and give you update.

Comment: Before 1.0 we have effectively changed the order to make it consistent across Tweetinvi and with Twitter.

Comment: I have updated to 1.0, streaming not working. Could you help take a look? Thanks a lot! https://gist.github.com/duoxu/0623a5c8d7c0ebcd49b31dea05f087c6

Comment: Can you please try to invert the Coordinates information. Version 0.9.13.0 and above is now following the ISO 6709 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709) and uses LAT/LON instead of LON/LAT.

Comment: I changed and still did not get any tweets. I even removed the filters (language and location), still no luck. When I changed to use SampleStream instead of FilteredStream, I saw some tweets coming. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!